# How can i get the Text from Mouse Right Click?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. And try to programming with C#
I have a Textfile with Texts. For Example: D23423P  34L211 5 I copy this Text from the Textfile with Mouse Right Click Copy to use this for my 17 TextBoxs. The TextBoxs has the Label: label1.

So i created to label1 a ContextMenuStrip: Paste and Cut:

```
private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string tempr = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
        textBox1.Paste(tempr);
}
```

If i click Paste the Function, i wanna get the Texts (D23423P  34L211 5 ) and fill the 17 TextBoxs for Example:

```
    textBox1: D
    textBox2: 2
    textBox3: 4
    ....
```

I clicked Right Click "Paste" i save the Data text in tempr. How can i set the textBox 1 with D textbox 2 with 2...?
Should i use the Methode String split?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a TextBox array in your class:

```
private const int TextBoxCount = 17;
private TextBox[] TextBoxArray;
```

And populate it somewhere in your form's constructor:

```
TextBoxArray = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3... };
```

In your paste function, loop through the string, and index with []:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
    TextBoxArray[i].Text = tempr[i];
```

Comment: Thank u that was my self Solution: ZB = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text); TextBox1.Text += ZB[0]; TextBox2.Text += ZB[1]; TextBox3.Text += ZB[2]; ....